# Unable to delete comments from facebook social comments plugin

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have integrated facebook social comments plugin: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments in my wordpress based website.

But when I have only 1 or 2 comments on my post, then if I try to delete my comment then the confirm dialog which appears doesn't show properly and which is why I am not able to delete the comment. It appears as attached.

[image]

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your bug should be fixed by now. You probably didn't do anything wrong yourself, since this was a transient issue with the Facebook Comments Plugin that got fixed by Facebook in the latest push.

You can find the Facebook bug report here:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1529893267311581